# PyTorch Lightning trainer.fit stuck at epoch 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pytorch-lightning

I was trying to make a multi-input model using PyTorch and PyTorch Lightning, but I can't figure out why the trainer is stuck at epoch 0. I'm trying to migrate this code from TensorFlow to PyTorch but the PyTorch learning curve is a bit steep and I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
RC_train_config = config.init_dataset_config(
'RC',
'GI4E',
'label',
16,
lr = 0.001,
epochs = 500,
train_ratio = 0.8
```

Configurations for the model, including the hyperparameter and the dataset used. It is also used for data selection since different datasets require different processing methods.

```
class RCDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, config_dataset):
    super().__init__()
    self.config_dataset = config_dataset
    
    # Image-handling
    if self.config_dataset['dataset'] == 'all':
        pass
    elif self.config_dataset['dataset'] == 'BIOID':
        if self.config_dataset['mode'] == 'label':
            pass
        elif self.config_dataset['mode'] == 'filter':
            pass
    elif self.config_dataset['dataset'] == 'GI4E':
        if self.config_dataset['mode'] == 'label':
            image1_noteye_paths = glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_label'] + '/0/noteye/*')
            image1_eye_paths = glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_label'] + '/0/left/*')
            image1_eye_paths += glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_label'] + '/0/right/*')
            
            image2_noteye_paths = glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_label'] + '/1/noteye/*')
            image2_eye_paths = glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_label'] + '/1/left/*')
            image2_eye_paths += glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_label'] + '/1/right/*')
            
            image3_noteye_paths = glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_label'] + '/2/noteye/*')
            image3_eye_paths = glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_label'] + '/2/left/*')
            image3_eye_paths += glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_label'] + '/2/right/*')
            
            count_eye = len(glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_label'] + '/2/left/*'))
        elif self.config_dataset['mode'] == 'filter':
            image1_noteye_paths = glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_filter'] + '/0/noteye/*')
            image1_eye_paths = glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_filter'] + '/0/left/*')
            image1_eye_paths += glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_filter'] + '/0/right/*')
            
            image2_noteye_paths = glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_filter'] + '/1/noteye/*')
            image2_eye_paths = glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_filter'] + '/1/left/*')
            image2_eye_paths += glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_filter'] + '/1/right/*')
            
            image3_noteye_paths = glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_filter'] + '/2/noteye/*')
            image3_eye_paths = glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_filter'] + '/2/left/*')
            image3_eye_paths += glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_filter'] + '/2/right/*')
            
            count_eye = len(glob(C.WORKING_DATASETS['GI4E']['images_filter'] + '/2/left/*'))
            
    self.image1_paths = image1_noteye_paths + image1_eye_paths
    self.image2_paths = image2_noteye_paths + image2_eye_paths
    self.image3_paths = image3_noteye_paths + image3_eye_paths
    
    # Label-handling
    label_noteye1 = torch.zeros(len(image1_noteye_paths))
    label_noteye2 = torch.zeros(len(image2_noteye_paths))
    label_noteye3 = torch.zeros(len(image3_noteye_paths))
    
    label_left = torch.ones(count_eye)
    label_right = torch.full([count_eye], 2)
    
    self.labels1 = torch.concat((label_noteye1, label_left, label_right))
    self.labels2 = torch.concat((label_noteye2, label_left, label_right))
    self.labels3 = torch.concat((label_noteye3, label_left, label_right))
           
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    image1 = None
    image2 = None
    image3 = None
    
    with Image.open(self.image1_paths[idx]) as img:
        image1(img)
        
    with Image.open(self.image2_paths[idx]) as img:
        image2(img)
        
    with Image.open(self.image3_paths[idx]) as img:
        image3(img)
        
    image1 = transforms.ToTensor()
    image2 = transforms.ToTensor()
    image3 = transforms.ToTensor()
            
    return image1, image2, image3, self.labels1[idx], self.labels2[idx], self.labels3[idx]

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.image1_paths)
```

Base PyTorch Dataset

```
class RCDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
def __init__(self, config_dataset: dict, mode: str):
    super().__init__()
    dataset = RCDataset(config_dataset)
    
    self.config_dataset = config_dataset
    
    self.data_train = []
    self.data_val = []
    self.data_test = []
    
    if mode == 'train':
        self.data_train, self.data_val = random_split(
            dataset,
            [round(len(dataset) * config_dataset['train_ratio']),
             round(len(dataset) * (config_dataset['testval_ratio'] * 2))]
        )
    elif mode == 'predict':
        self.data_test = dataset
    
def train_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(
        self.data_train,
        batch_size=self.config_dataset['batch_size'],
        num_workers=12
    )

def val_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(
        self.data_val,
        batch_size=self.config_dataset['batch_size'],
        num_workers=12
    )

def predict_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(
        self.data_test,
        batch_size=self.config_dataset['batch_size'],
        num_workers=12
    )
```

Lightning Wrapper

```
class RCBase(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    #RC1
    self.RC1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=5, stride=2, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.Linear(64, 64),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(64, 3),
        nn.Softmax(1)
    )
    
    #RC2
    self.RC2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=5, stride=2, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.Linear(64, 64),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(64, 3),
        nn.Softmax(1)
    )
    
    #RC3
    self.RC3 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=5, stride=2, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.Linear(64, 64),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(64, 3),
        nn.Softmax(1)
    )
    
def forward(self, img1, img2, img3):
    output1 = self.RC1(img1)
    output2 = self.RC2(img2)
    output3 = self.RC3(img3)
    
    return output1, output2, output
```

Base PyTorch model

```
class RCPL(pl.LightningModule):
def __init__(self, config_dataset: dict):
    super().__init__()
    self.RC_base = RCBase()
    self.config_dataset = config_dataset

def forward(self, img1, img2, img3):
    output1, output2, output3 = self.RC_base(img1, img2, img3)
    
    return output1, output2, output3

def configure_optimizers(self):
    return optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.config_dataset['lr'])
    
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    img1, img2, img3, lbl1, lbl2, lbl3 = batch
    output1, output2, output3 = self.RC_base(img1, img2, img3)
    
    train_loss1 = F.cross_entropy(output1, lbl1)
    train_loss2 = F.cross_entropy(output2, lbl2)
    train_loss3 = F.cross_entropy(output3, lbl3)
    
    avg_loss = (train_loss1 + train_loss2 + train_loss3) / 3
    
    self.log('avg_train_loss', avg_loss, on_epoch = True)
    self.log('train_loss1', train_loss1, on_epoch = True)
    self.log('train_loss2', train_loss2, on_epoch = True)
    self.log('train_loss3', train_loss3, on_epoch = True)
    
    return avg_loss, train_loss1, train_loss2, train_loss3

def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    img1, img2, img3, lbl1, lbl2, lbl3 = batch
    output1, output2, output3 = self.RC_base(img1, img2, img3)
    
    val_loss1 = F.cross_entropy(output1, lbl1)
    val_loss2 = F.cross_entropy(output2, lbl2)
    val_loss3 = F.cross_entropy(output3, lbl3)
    
    avg_val_loss = (val_loss1 + val_loss2 + val_loss3) / 3
    
    self.log('avg_val_loss', avg_val_loss, on_epoch = True)
    self.log('val_loss1', val_loss1, on_epoch = True)
    self.log('val_loss2', val_loss2, on_epoch = True)
    self.log('val_loss3', val_loss3, on_epoch = True)

def predict_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    img1, img2, img3, lbl1, lbl2, lbl3 = batch
    
    return self(img1, img2, img3)
```

PyTorch model wrapper.

Coming from TensorFlow to PyTorch is a bit hard since everything is more automated and intuitive to use in TensorFlow. There's no error output produced here so I'm just not sure what's wrong with this.

Output (Simplified for readability):

LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]

- 239 K Trainable params
- 0 Non-trainable params
- 239 K Total params
- 0.958 Total estimated model params size (MB)

Epoch 0:   0%|          | 0/782 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

Comment: Same problem. I'm using `openspeech` (based on pytorch & pytorch lightning), and training stuck at epoch 0 and terminates without any errors. Succeeding lines were no longer executed.

Comment: BTW. Update, it's memory issue. Try to lower down other hyper-parameters to see any improvements ...